# different select options depending on the row

Tags: breeze, knockout-2.0

I have a table set up like this

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Look</th>
                <th>Lease Company</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: leaseApplicationLooks">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: lookId"></td> 
                <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.leaseCompanies, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name', value: leaseCompany" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My view model:

```
leaseCompanies(datacontext.lookups.applicationCompanies);
```

This returns an array with a name, type fields

Depending on the row I want to display different options:

For example:
Row 1, show all Type = 1, 2
Row 2, show all Type = 2

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a different array for each of the types you want.  If they are dynamic in length then set up child observable arrays of your leaseApplicationLooks and populate those by iterating through you list of lease companies.  It's pretty simple actual, just use plain all javascript loops

Comment: How would I call each different array in my table?  Specifically, what would my options: [what code here] be?  From this: <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.leaseCompanies, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name', value: leaseCompany" /></td>